# How can I deploy a service fabric cluster with nodes that span multiple locations?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am thinking to create a service fabric cluster with nodes that span multiple locations, for example, one cluster that has nodes at eastus and westus2. Do you know how I can do it? Is there any ARM template examples? I saw MSDN document mentioned this in service fabric cluster disaster recovery. But nothing else useful I found out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not officially supported at this time. The main problem is designating VM scale sets with their proper fault domains. You need to have a way to make sure the Stateful Service & Actors data is always replicated to the other region, so you can indeed do fail-over.